# How to place image in source folder and use it in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, image, import

I am teaching myself how to use images in Eclipse.

I am trying to get my code implementing images to compile:

```
    import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import java.io.File;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;

public class ImageDemo extends Canvas
{
    Image coolFace;

    public ImageDemo() throws Exception
    {
        coolFace = ImageIO.read( new File("jesus.png") );

    }

    public void paint( Graphics g )
    {
        //           Image  , x,  y, this
        g.drawImage(coolFace,100,100,this);

        g.setColor( Color.yellow );
        g.drawOval(88,88,70,25);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
    {
        JFrame win = new JFrame("Image Demo");
        win.setSize(1024,768);
        win.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        win.add( new ImageDemo() );
        win.setVisible(true);
    }


}
```

The problem is that I do not know how to get my image in the same source folder of my code in Eclipse.

I think I created one but I do not know how to put an image from my Desktop there.

Any help would be appreciated. [image: Eclipse]

Comment: You could stick it in the project root folder; the same one that contains e.g. ".classpath", ".project", and "src". That's the default startup working directory for Eclipse run configurations. You can put it there by showing the project explorer view and just dragging it there.

Comment: Alternatively if you place your images in classpath you can use ClassLoader.getResourceAsStream()

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generally eclipse starts jvm with current directory from base of the project so place it on base of the project to read it with existing code